# Difference in Feature selection methods between classification and regression problems?

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, high-dimensional

For high-dimensional molecular genetic data, is there a difference in available feature selection techniques between classification problems and regression problems? Or can all feature selection techniques be applied to either classification and regression modeling indiscriminately?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference.  Classification has the efficiency of the sign test at best ($\frac{2}{\pi}$) whereas prediction can use all the information in the data and will work better on new samples.  When using classification, the entire classification scheme may have to be re-done from scratch if you alter the outcome prevalence through oversampling.

Classification uses an improper accuracy scoring rule which is easily fooled into selecting the wrong features.

For more detail see [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat) Sections 18.3.5 and 18.4 and listen to the audio.

Comment: Thans for the answer Frank. In the second sentence, I think you meant to say regression instead of prediction, right?

Comment: No I meant prediction, but that is often done with regression.

Comment: Hi Frank, could you recommend some feature selection techniques for regression problems?

Comment: There are not many that I would recommend whether using regression or some other method, because the data are usually incapable of telling you which features are "important".  If you have to use feature selection, i.e., if you are less interested in prediction per se, I'd recommend methods that combine appropriate shrinkage with selection, e.g., the elastic net.

Comment: It's microarray data so I have to perform some kind of feature selection, because otherwise the Machine Learning part for predicting will take a long time to compute with half a million features.

Comment: But why wouldn't you recommend any feature selection? Shouldn't one overcome overfitting problems and curse of dimensionality when modeling with too many predictors?

Comment: Feature selection would only help with overfitting if the features deleted were pre-specified and you didn't have to use some of your information to decide which ones to delete.  Empirical decisions about dropping predictors has nothing to do with solving the curse of dimensionality.  There is no reason in general why feature selection is consonant with optimal prediction.  When you have to "name names" you spend some of your information and discard predictors that have some information.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Frank. Nonetheless, you are confusing me. All these articles that I read on microarray data (where p>>n problem), they all say that feature selection is the way to go for multiple reasons (one is discussed above). Or does this only apply for lets say a classification problem where we want to find biomarkers that are discriminating between health and disease state? In this case we want a sparse model, because most variables are irrelevant and not correlated with the disease state. If we know that there are only a few latent variables, shouldn't we apply feature selection?

Comment: Having a sparse model is only really a good idea if you know in advance which factors are related to the outcome.  But if you knew that why would you include the others in the analysis?  The articles to which you refer are badly informed, and they ignore the fact that if you did bootstrapping their "method" would find different "important" predictors at each resample of the dataset.

Comment: Well that's strange because really all articles on feature selection for microarray data claim that one should definitely use feature selection. Also it is an established thing among bioinformaticians handling such data. Do you have expertise in this field? Because I cannot believe that all articles are wrong about this if it is such a well established "have to".

Comment: I mean I see you are a professor of biostatistics, but do you have expertise on microarrays. Because really all heavily cited articles put in their introduction that feature selection is obligatory.

Comment: Yes I've done a good deal of study and practice on high-dimensional multivariable models.  Bioinformaticians frequently use one-at-a-time feature selection, only because it's fast and easy to program, then they wonder why the selected features don't have much signal in them and they never study the volatility in feature selection.